# Django Rest Framework - Automatically create new model B instance each and every time new model A instance is created

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

As said in the title. I want my django rest framework to create new model B object instance - with foreign key to model A , each and every time new model A object instance is created, so that they have foreign key relation.  Currently i use ViewSets. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can not create a relation to the object when the instance is created, since it will not have a primary key until saved. Use a hook to make sure the object is created after saving.

Comment: i would like to say bit thanks for helping me, i rearranged my models and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-save)/[pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#pre-save) signals.

Comment: thanks that helped me a lot, i did some research and found out it is a amazing tool.